# Windows.Forms.TabControl changing SelectedIndex upon focus

Tags: .net, tabcontrol

I am using the tabcontrol with 4 tabs.  The tab is not in focus but tab 0 is displayed.  When I click on a button on tab0, the GotFocus event shows the SelectedIndex as 0 .. as I would expect.  But then the tabControl.Selecting event is triggered.  In this event the SelectedIndex is now 4, the last tab.

What is changing the Index??  Again, I am just clicking on a button that is on Tab 0.  The event of that button is not triggered.

I would expect the tab index to stay at 0 on the return focus and the button click event to be triggered.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet or a repro? Also, is the last tab opening?

Comment: You see the old tab index. Have a look at MSDN documentation. [Selecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting) event fires *before* tab changes (and before `SelectedIndex` is updated). You want [Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected) event instead.